# Content view of Activity resized on create

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingmenu

I noticed a strange behavior in my app. When I launch it, I can see my content view resized.
[image: See the black bar under FAB]
Then it resized to correct position.
[image]
I tracked debugger value, found layout size changed.

This activity doesn't really use ActionBar, it's a custom view on the top.

The view has `FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` and `FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY` flag set.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `Window.setBackgroundDrawable`. I use SlidingMenu in this Activity, set window background to SlidingMenu's content, and set window background to null. This causes window resize.

To fix this, simply set ColorDrawable with transparent color instead of null.